# Less formal equivalent of " like a gentleman "

Tags: dialectal-equivalent

There is " like a gentleman ", as in : *" Act like a gentleman "* / *" You're a gentleman, act like one "*.

Is there anything less formal ? " *Like a dood* " maybe ? or simply " *behave* " ?

Comment: 'Behave yourself' works, I find. It is up to oneself to behave, irrespective of others . Welcome to EL&U.

Comment: In many Jewish communities, or in areas where such communities have had significant influence, you might also hear "be a _mensch_". (_Mensch_ is a Yiddish word, which in this context more-or-less means "a respectable person".)

Comment: **like a gent**? That is less formal, but so like the original that I am unsure that it counts, so I am not offering it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways!

Your alternative of "behave" works.

You could also say...

"Act cordially."

"Be respectful."

"Act warmly/kindly/politely."

"Be civil."

"Be courteous."

"Be hospitable."

There are many, many more ways you could word it but there's a few for you to consider.  I wouldn't go with dood, though, unless you're referring to Dudeism.  Ha!

"Act like The Dude, you fool!"

Answer (score 1):

A calm "manners, please" will usually suffice. Or "mind your (manners/language/self)" is also appropriate.

I find it difficult to use "behave" without at least thinking of the Carry On films. It always feels a little double entendre to me.